# In new Google Sheets, how can I import data from other spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have the same problem with this topic [How do I link a cell in Google Spreadsheets to a cell in another document?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/786/how-do-i-link-a-cell-in-google-spreadsheets-to-a-cell-in-another-document) and they suggest to use `IMPORTRANGE()` with `key` inside but I didn't see any `key` in my sheet URL.

I have one Google survey form for gathering many data from our staff and raw data will generate to Google Sheets as `report(Responses)`.

I need to import raw data from `report(Responses)` to other Google Sheets and summarize a report in it.

How can I get data from this sheet?

Comment: the key in your spreadsheet url is: 1luMCGc3UFMbzkWJYFkvJWUsme3YxlNPmA1QlU66Nxxx (how i know that? not an idea. I asked flame vision but got spreadsheet key vision instead of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMPORTRANGE() is currently not supported in the new google sheets. It will be supported in future but at the moment no one knows when exactly.

You can switch back to the old google sheets where IMPORTRANGE() is still working as usual. Or you can use a script e.g.:

```
function myImportRange( key , sheetrange) {
 var shra = sheetrange.split("!") ;
 if (shra.length==1) shra[1]=shra[0], shra[0]="";  

 var sheetstring = shra[0].replace( /'/g , "")
 var rangestring = shra[1] 

 var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById( key )    
 if ( sheetstring.length==0 ) sheet = source.getSheets()[0] ;
 else sheet = source.getSheetByName(sheetstring) ;

 return  sheet.getRange( rangestring ).getValues(); 
}
```

You can find the original post of this script written by Ahab here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/docs/how-do-i/f_r7iVtUThM

**Edit:** IMPORTRANGE () is now supported.

Comment: @mister-vanderbilt. Is it supported? Where can I find the key parameter?

Comment: Check the URL of your sheet. 

Let's say you have docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gj.......RoUJ4i/ as URL.
Than your key would be the part between the last two slashes, in this case "1gj.......RoUJ4i". So an IMPORTRANGE call could be like 
=IMPORTRANGE("1gj.......RoUJ4i";"tab!A1:B2")

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by using the entire URL of the source sheet:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/a/myCompany.com/spreadsheets/d/1ybGlQNGhY2l5INHCz-XYhhsgRiTBBJiScKM490hQcU","'Rental Properties'!A:AX")
```

**Note**: when I first put this formula into my destination sheet, I got a `REF` error.  If you mouse over the cell there is a pop up that says you need to "Connect" the sheets and a button that says `Allow access`.  Click the button.  A message saying `Adding permissions...` appears.  Shortly afterward my data appeared.

Comment: My sheets got "upgraded" today (i.e. broken). I follow the instructions on this answer and everything as described until it says `Adding permissions`. It just hangs there and nothing happens. I never get to see my imported data...

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed my problem by closing all sheets, logging out, and going back in again. Then I was able to `Allow access` and everything worked.